# What is the keyboard shortcut (in Visual Studio 2008) to show method definition?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm thinking about the windows that pops up right after you type the opening bracket.

EDIT: I meant the tooltip :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean the tooltip with the arguments to the function?  Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your language.

Since you are talking braces I am going to assume C#, not C++

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en) is a poster of default short cuts for C#

Go to Definition is <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: I meant the tooltip, sorry if it wasn't clear.
Anyway thanks for the poster link.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever key sequence is assigned to the "Edit.ParameterInfo" command in Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard.